# Search Inside Dropdown with data in tree structure React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, nested, dropdown

I have developed a custom component which renders dropdown with a tree like structure inside it and allows the user to search for values inside the dropdown. Somehow the search works only after two levels of the tree structure.

We would be able to search only on the inside of NextJS label. The previous levels do not render results.

My function looks like this:

```
const searchFunction = (menu: treeData[], searchText: string) => {
        debugger; //eslint-disable-line no-debugger
        for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
            if (menu[i].name.includes(searchText)) {
                setFound(true);
                return menu[i].name;
            } else if (!menu[i].name.includes(searchText)) {
                if (menu[i].children !== undefined) {
                    return searchFunction(menu[i].children, searchText);
                }
            } else {
                return 'Not Found';
            }
        }
    };  

And My data is like this:  
import { treeData } from './DdrTreeDropdown.types';

export const menu: treeData[] = [
    {
        name: 'Web Project',

        children: [
            {
                name: 'NextJS',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'MongoDB',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Backend',
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: 'NodeJS',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: 'ReactJS',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'Express',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'mysql',
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: 'jwt',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'lorem project',

        children: [
            {
                name: 'Vue Js',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'Oracle Db',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'JDBC',
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: 'Java',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: 'ReactJS',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'Express',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'mysql',
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: 'jwt',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

The sandbox link of the component is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-feynman-89ozi?file=/src/styles.ts

Comment: What I see in the picture is not 'nested dropdowns', but a dropdown with a tree hierarchy of items in it. I suggest to fix your question text to make it more understandable

Comment: You need to write a recusrive function

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky see i have written a recursive function but it is not producing the expected result. Some problem with the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at the context that this is used in, so apologies if I'm missing something about how this is supposed to work. I've assumed that you can call setFound after running this function based on whether it finds anything or not and that it only needs to return one value. But hopefully this helps.

```js
const menu = [{"name":"Web Project","children":[{"name":"NextJS","children":[{"name":"MongoDB"},{"name":"Backend","children":[{"name":"NodeJS"}]}]},{"name":"ReactJS","children":[{"name":"Express"},{"name":"mysql","children":[{"name":"jwt"}]}]}]},{"name":"lorem project","children":[{"name":"Vue Js","children":[{"name":"Oracle Db"},{"name":"JDBC","children":[{"name":"Java"}]}]},{"name":"ReactJS","children":[{"name":"Express"},{"name":"mysql","children":[{"name":"jwt"}]}]}]}];

const searchFunction = (menu, searchText) => {
  let result;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    if(menu[i].name.includes(searchText)) {
      return menu[i].name;
    } else if(menu[i].children !== undefined) {
      result = searchFunction(menu[i].children, searchText);
      if(result) return result;
    }
  }
  
  return null;
};

console.log(searchFunction(menu, 'NextJS'));
console.log(searchFunction(menu, 'jwt'));
console.log(searchFunction(menu, 'foo'));
```

Looking at why the current version doesn't work, I think it goes something like this:

- Let's take 'jwt' as the searchText.
- We start in the 'Web Project' object, the name does not match, so we go to the else if block (BTW, we can never reach the else block as the else if condition is the opposite of the if condition).
- The 'Web Project' object does have children so we will return from the new call to searchFunction; notice that 'lorem project' can never be reached as we will (regardless of the result) return the value of searchFunction and skip the rest of the loop.
- Inside of our new and subsequent calls to searchFunction the same is going to happen until we find either a matching item or an item without children.
  If we get to an item without children the the loop will successfully carry on to the siblings of the item.
- If it doesn't find a match or an item with children it will exit the for loop and return undefined up the chain to the caller of the initial searchFunction.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate @BenStephens !! Yeah after the explanation you gave i got what went wrong. I am quite new here so lets hope i can catch up with you guys soon.